# MySQL - Insert into a table and get the ID of this to insert into another table -- all in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a **`exercise_logs`** table with these columns:

`user_id | exercise_name | mood_log_id | weight_log_id | stretch_log_id`

I have three tables (**`mood_logs`**, **`weight_logs`** and **`stretch_logs`**) whose primary key is stored in the 3 last three respective columns in `exercise_logs`.

These are columns my **`mood_logs`** table:

`id | mood_scale`

---

So I want to create a new `mood_logs` entry and use the `id` from that and store that in  `exercise_log`. But I want to do it all in one query.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
INSERT INTO `exercise_logs` (`exercise_name`, `user_id`, `mood_log_id`)
    values('Breathing', 190, (INSERT INTO `mood_logs` (`mood_scale`)
                values(9); LAST_INSERT_ID()))
```

But this does not work.

Is it possible to achieve this in one query?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
First query insert into `mood_logs`

```
INSERT INTO `mood_logs` (`mood_scale`)
                values(9);
```

2nd Query insert into `exercise_logs`

```
 INSERT INTO `exercise_logs` (`exercise_name`, `user_id`, `mood_log_id`)
        values('Breathing', 190, (SELECT `mood_scale` FROM `mood_logs` WHERE `mood_scale` = 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to `INSERT` a row into `mood_logs`.

As the latest inserted id is from the above statement.

You can use `last_insert_id()` directly within the second insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO `mood_logs` (`mood_scale`) values (9);
INSERT INTO `exercise_logs` (`exercise_name`, `user_id`, `mood_log_id`) values('Breathing', 190, last_insert_id());
```

This is assuming you're the only using the database. If someone else uses an INSERT statement before you can use the `last_insert_id()` then, the id MIGHT be equal to whatever id the latest insert statement.

Can also use variables to store the `last_insert_id()`;

```
INSERT INTO `mood_logs` (`mood_scale`) values (9);
SET @arbitraryVariableName = last_insert_id();
INSERT INTO `exercise_logs` (`exercise_name`, `user_id`, `mood_log_id`) values('Breathing', 190, @arbitraryVariableName);
```